# Using an if statement in a dataframe with lambda functions

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, conditional-statements

I am trying to add a new column to a dataframe based on an if statement depending on the values of two columns. i.e. if column x == None then column y else column x

below is the script I have written but doesn't work. any ideas?

```
dfCurrentReportResults['Retention'] =  dfCurrentReportResults.apply(lambda x : x.Retention_y if x.Retention_x == None else x.Retention_x)
```

Also I got this error message:
    AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'Retention_x'", u'occurred at index BUSINESSUNIT_NAME')

fyi: BUSINESSUNIT_NAME is the first column name

Additional Info:

My data printed out looks like this and I want to add a 3rd column to take a value if there is one else keep NaN.

```
   Retention_x  Retention_y
0            1          NaN
1          NaN     0.672183
2          NaN     1.035613
3          NaN     0.771469
4          NaN     0.916667
5          NaN          NaN
6          NaN          NaN
7          NaN          NaN
8          NaN          NaN
9          NaN          NaN
```

**UPDATE:**
In the end I was having issues referencing the Null or is Null in my dataframe the final line of code I used also including the axis = 1 answered my question.

```
 dfCurrentReportResults['RetentionLambda'] = dfCurrentReportResults.apply(lambda x : x['Retention_y'] if pd.isnull(x['Retention_x']) else x['Retention_x'], axis = 1)
```

Thanks @EdChum, @strim099 and @aus_lacy for all your input. As my data set gets larger I may switch to the np.where option if I notice performance issues.

Comment: is `None` a string or a `NaN`? And could you provide a sample set of your data frame so we can better debug any issues?

Comment: @aus_lacy my use of None was basically an attempt to identify if the value is empty, so I guess it is a NaN and is None?

Comment: what column are you calling your `apply` on? A sample of your data would help you get an answer much quicker.

Comment: I would like to apply the function to the new column and get the results by referencing the other two columns. The data is a bit messy and also confidentially, i will try and knock together some simple data for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'r lambda is operating on the 0 axis which is columnwise. Simply add `axis=1` to the `apply` arg list. This is clearly documented.

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: dfCurrentReportResults = pandas.DataFrame([['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f'],['g','h'],['i','j']], columns=['Retention_y', 'Retention_x'])

In [3]: dfCurrentReportResults['Retention_x'][1] = None

In [4]: dfCurrentReportResults['Retention_x'][3] = None

In [5]: dfCurrentReportResults
Out[5]:
  Retention_y Retention_x
0           a           b
1           c        None
2           e           f
3           g        None
4           i           j

In [6]: dfCurrentReportResults['Retention'] =  dfCurrentReportResults.apply(lambda x : x.Retention_y if x.Retention_x == None else x.Retention_x, axis=1)

In [7]: dfCurrentReportResults
Out[7]:
  Retention_y Retention_x Retention
0           a           b         b
1           c        None         c
2           e           f         f
3           g        None         g
4           i           j         j
```

Comment: thanks strimp099 actually I had tried adding axis = 1 in some of my attempts but got the same message. I think the issue is also that my dataframe value is probably not None, i.e. where you have None I have just a blank. is it the same thing or how can i reference the blank if I can't use None?

Comment: Actually anyway when I copy your code above and run your sample data i get this error: AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'Retention_x'", u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: how do you recreate your example to be NaN instead of None?

Comment: Assuming you're using numpy, just change your lambda function from `x.Retention_x == None` to `numpy.isnan(x.Retention_x)`

Comment: Ok in the end this works. dfCurrentReportResults['RetentionLambda'] = dfCurrentReportResults.apply(lambda x : x['Retention_y'] if pd.isnull(x['Retention_x']) else x['Retention_x'], axis = 1)      I didnt test your numpy.isnan(x.Retention_x) but i am sure that works as well so in the end i was just having issues with how to reference a NAN in my Lambda. I am marking your answer as correct because it is the closest solution for the title of the question I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `np.where`:

```
dfCurrentReportResults['Retention'] =  np.where(df.Retention_x == None, df.Retention_y, else df.Retention_x)
```

This uses the test condition, the first param and sets the value to `df.Retention_y` else `df.Retention_x`

also avoid using `apply` where possible as this is just going to loop over the values, `np.where` is a vectorised method and will scale much better.

**UPDATE**

OK no need to use `np.where` just use the following simpler syntax:

```
dfCurrentReportResults['Retention'] =  df.Retention_y.where(df.Retention_x == None, df.Retention_x)
```

**Further update**

```
dfCurrentReportResults['Retention'] =  df.Retention_y.where(df.Retention_x.isnull(), df.Retention_x)
```

Comment: @DSM I sometimes find the frames and series `where` syntax slightly confusing a while back due to some subtle differences so I started using `np.where` from that point on, maybe time to go back and look at it again, I'll post an update, thanks

Comment: I was getting a syntex error on the np.where line. the updated line runs but gives me the following error...TypeError: Could not compare <type 'NoneType'> type with Series

Comment: I still find `numpy` syntax easier to read: `dfCurrentReportResults['Retention'] =  np.where(df.Retention_x.isnull(), df.Retention_y, df.Retention_x)` but that is almost completely objective.

Comment: Thanks EdChum your solution using .where also worked fine as another option and in the end I def will use that in future solutions. The final code I used to get yours to work was the following dfCurrentReportResults['RetentionWHERE'] = dfCurrentReportResults.Retention_y.where(dfCurrentReportResults.Retention_x.isnull(), dfCurrentReportResults.Retention_x)

Comment: @IcemanBerlin no worries, the key thing to take away from this is to look for a vectorised method that will operate on the whole df or series rather than calling apply which loops over the values